# Widget API accepts clean friendly URLs

Tags: soundcloud

In the past the widget HTML5 player API was not accepting sound clean friendly URLs,
only with a track ID.

But now when I try it, it seems that it does works fine, but I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the official blog or something.

So my question is: is it safe to use it please?

Using:
    http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://soundcloud.com/user-name/track-name
Instead of: 
http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13692671

And also if you got any status of fixing the serious bug where the events are not firing, I will love to know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events should be all firing properly now.

Yes, you can use friendly URLs, however, as we have to resolve them on our side, initial load of the widget will be a tad slower. So for the faster loading it is still recommended to use API URLs.

Comment: Thank you Misha for your answer, good to know we can safely use friendly URLs too.
About the events, unfortunately they are still not firing, if they do for you, can you please share a basic example (besides of the "READY" that does works, I think).

Comment: Hey Gil, I have now verified there are still some problems in Widget API that have to do with redirects from `https` to `http`. Please try to use `https` in the widget source as a quick fix, while we are investigating. Sorry for inconvenience. If that doesn't work, please be so kind and specify what exactly doesn't work for you (the best would be to use jsbin.com to communicate the issue)

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing to `https` but sadly that didn't helped, here's a link to a testing page on "jsbin" : [link](http://jsbin.com/ugebij/1/edit)

Comment: Here's the fixed example: http://jsbin.com/ugebij/5/edit Note that the script needs to be placed before closing `</body>` tag or you’d have to use some kind of DOM `ready` event (like jQuery’s).